# How to read data from PIR sensor which is controlled by relay i2c?

Tags: python, i2c, c, wiringpi

There are my first steps with RPi and i2c. I use expander pcf8574 and I would like to drive a relay to control LED and PIR sensor. When the state on sensor is HIGH, LED should be turn on. I wrote a script, which control LED, but I don't know how to read the state from PIR. I found function:

```
int wiringPiI2CRead (int fd)
```

but I can't use it properly to read a state (low or high) or it isnt correct function to read data from sensor. I know basics of programming so I need only one line like

```
int data = //function, which give a state from sensor
```

Below is a script. In python code it will be also right.

```
#include <wiringpi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

int main (void)
{
  int fd; 
  wiringPiSetup();
  fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x20);


 while (1) 
  {   
      if(......) > 0)) { //in this line I don't know how to read data
      wiringPiI2CWrite(fd,0x24);  //PIR Sensor ready, LED ON
      print('Motion Detected');
      delay(500);
     }
      wiringPiI2CWrite(fd,0x25);  //PIR Sensor ready, LED OFF
      delay(500);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `PIR sensor which is controlled by relay` .... what does this actually mean? does the relay turn power on and off to the PIR sensor?

Comment: You need to read the specs of the PCF8574, in particular how it is controlled with I2C.  It's not our job to read the specs for you.